# Blackberry Jad file testing not possible?

Tags: cordova, blackberry

Recently i developed an application in the phonegap. When i build the application i got all the output files like apk,xpa,ipa,jad. All the windows,ios and android outputs are working fine.

Coming to the blackberry i got the **.jad** file. When i install the instaltion is not possible. I don't know why it is happened. I downloaded **BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators 6.0.0** when i goto file browse that is asking only cod file.

If i want to install can i convert that to cod file?is there any converts for cod file? If we want cod file what is the use of jad when i got from the phonegap build. please clarify me.

Thanks&Regards
Shankar

Answer (score 0):

A JAD file is a directory for a Java MIDlet that is normally accompanied by a JAR file. In the BBOS architecture the JAR file is replaced with a COD file. I just had a look at the Cordova getting started with BlackBerry document which specifies using a tool delivered with the SDK to install the application on the simulator. Perhapse this tool can find the COD file.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html